# Half-lap joints without table saw

Tags: joinery

The information I have so far show that half-lap joints are made using table saw. However, it should still be possible to make them without table saw by using some other jig while getting clean joints with the correct dimensions on both sides of the joint.

What is the correct way to make half-lap joints without using table saw? Is it using circular saw with chisel or using wood router or something else? Are there any jigs that can help?

Comment: There is no one "correct" way. You could make them with a router (table-mounted or handheld), you could use a handsaw or multiple ones (crosscut and rip), a hand plane, and a chisel. You could do it all with chisels. You could use a rabbeting plane. If you can think of a way to cut wood, you could probably incorporate it into the job somehow.

Comment: OK, lets put some constraints. Say that the person is not a carpentar but a DIYer. Has almost no experience with wood working and does not have a table saw because it seems expensive and terrifying. Now, which method would give the best result? It seems a simple saw should do it. Does it matter if the cut is not removing material at exactly 50% width mark on both pieces of wood that have to be joined?

Comment: Please [edit] that information into your question.

Comment: As far as your last sentence - no, it doesn't have to be *exactly* 50:50, but the two pieces of the joint need to be fitted together so the final surface is smooth. I would aim for 50:50, of course, but a little bit of variability in one direction or the other is fine as long as the other piece compensates for it.

Comment: The "best" method is the one that the person has the tools for and the knowledge to use them properly in order to achieve the desired result. If they can't chisel a surface flat to save their life, then using chisels is the wrong way to go. The answer is entirely dependent on the person. As I indicated in my first comment, which method is used to remove and shape the wood is practically irrelevant - it's the results that count.

Comment: so if the two sides are add to less than 50, what is done in that case? If they adding to more than 100%, we could just sand it off or maybe just leave it?

Comment: Ideally, the two sides add up to 100%, as that is the only way to achieve a flat surface on the joined boards. Better to initially cut them slightly oversize, then use your favorite method to remove wood from one until they fit. For the most *repeatable* results, a handheld adjustable router or router table with the respective appropriate jigs would be ***my*** method of choice, as you can remove very small amounts of wood by making very slight adjustments to the height. Once you dial in the height at exactly 50%, you can cut both pieces of wood at the same time. Use a straight router bit.

Comment: *"The information I have so far show that half-lap joints are made using table saw."* Pardon how this sounds, but this clearly shows you haven't looked very hard! On YT alone there must be dozens of videos showing alternate methods. SE isn't set up to do research for you, it's not a "let me Google that for you" service. **It's to help you if your research fails to find what you're looking for**. This is why it's so important to list some/all of the links you've found, so that e.g. Answers don't include links that you've already found, or repeat info you've read but isn't suitable in some way.

Comment: Most videos show use of table saw. There are a small number that show alternate methods. However, what I did not know is if they are just trying to show off or this is something that needs to be taken seriously.

Comment: The "best" method will vary depending on your goals and what tools you have available. Want to justify buying a bandsaw? Then clearly a bandsaw is the best method. All you have are chisels and a circular saw, and no budget for new tools right now? Then that's the best method. Want to improve your handsaw skills? Use a handsaw. Whatever you decide is best for you, do some research on that particular method, then if something is unclear about that method or you've tried it with poor results, please come back and rewrite your question to reflect that more specific challenge.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it using circular saw with chisel or using wood router or something else?

Yes (to all of those options).  I made my first half-lap joint in school with a handsaw and chisel.

What tools do you have? What tools could you justify acquiring for this and upcoming projects?

I have a table saw, a circular saw, *and* a router (plus hand saws and chisels).  I would probably:

- use the circular saw (not the table saw) to cut the end of the lap joints (probably not to full depth),
- break up the body of the material to be removed with an additional cut or two
- knock out most of the wood to be removed with a chisel
- finish the joint with a router

The advantage of that approach is that the finished joint is made by the router, which I find to be the most precise and controllable of my tools (so I can get the depths *exactly* right).  On the other hand *most* of the wood is removed as sensible sized chunks rather than fine sawdust you have to keep out of your lungs.

Depending on the sort of DIY you normally do, you may not be able to justify a router to yourself and SO.  In that case I would use the circular saw to cut almost exactly to depth with several cuts a few mm apart, and then use a hand chisel to finish off.  (I can't imagine doing DIY without a circular saw.)

Comment: hand saws, how many saws could that be? I bought router since it seemed to be a cool device being able to do so much stuff and is not terrifying like the table saw and chain saw.

Comment: @quantum231  big (530mm) panel saw, small (370mm) panel saw and a 230mm pull saw for detail work.  The pull saw is too big really, it should be more like 150mm.  I don't (and my father didn't) have a tool problem.  I can stop buying them any time I want to; I just don't want to.

Comment: I've done "lots and lots" of them with a circular saw and a big, wide chisel. Easy-peasy.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a beginner in woodworking, and will admit to only having tried making joint cuts a handful of times. Because I'm not comfortable working with jigs yet, I use manual tools (coping saw, handsaw, wood chisel, etc). It gets the job done and the result is not too shabby.
Long way of saying you don't necessarily need power tools to make your joints. It's more time-consuming, but I figure it's the best way to learn.